# Form: Height of TextField until the end of page

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe, javascript

I have a tabular arrangement of Textfields.

Is there a simple method to enlarge the text field down below -dynamically- until the end of the page?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot, includehead, 
showframe=false
headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[ headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{Some stuff here... \\ Some stuff there...}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Some stuff here...

\bigskip
Please describe:\par
\begin{Form}
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % yes you need this
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.5\fboxrule}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{b{0.5\textwidth}  X }
\TextField[name=box0,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 0,width=0.5\textwidth, height=10cm]{}
&
\noindent\TextField[name=box1,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 1,width=0.5\textwidth, height=10cm]{}
\\[-0.3\normalbaselineskip]
\TextField[name=box2,multiline,borderstyle=S, 
             value=Text 2, height=10cm, width=\textwidth]{}{}
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot, includehead,
showframe=true,
headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[ headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{Some stuff here... \\ Some stuff there...}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcommand\fieldheight{}
\begin{document}
Some stuff here...

\bigskip
Please describe:\par
\edef\fieldheight{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-10cm\relax}
\begin{Form}
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2}% % yes you need this
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}%
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.5\fboxrule}%
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{b{0.5\textwidth}  X }
\TextField[name=box0,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 0,width=0.5\textwidth, height=10cm]{}
&
\noindent\TextField[name=box1,multiline,borderstyle=S, value=Text 1,width=0.5\textwidth, height=10cm]{}
\\[-0.3\normalbaselineskip]
\TextField[name=box2,multiline,borderstyle=S,
             value=Text 2, height=\fieldheight, width=\textwidth]{}{}
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But there is still a big gap / whitespace.